# Unable to create class for custom droplet | ATG 11.1 | Jboss 6.1

Tags: jboss6.x, atg

I'm using ATG 11.1 and Jboss 6.1. I created a sample ATG project and wrote a custom droplet in it. used runAssembler cmd to create ear. deployment was successful but getting below error.

Am I missing anything ? can anybody please help me on this.

**Command to create ear**
runAssembler -server "atg_production" -jboss "C:\ProgramData\6.1.0_geppetto\core-app\deployments\core.ear" -m Production

Manifest-Version: 1.0
ATG-Config-Path: config/
ATG-Required: DafEar.Admin DPS DSS DCS DAF DAF.Deployment DAF.DeploymentAgent DAS DCS.PublishingAgent PublishingAgent REST PublishingAgent
ATG-J2EE: j2ee-apps/web-app
ATG-EAR-Module: j2ee-apps/web-app
ATG-Class-Path: classes bin
ATG-Client-Update-File: true
ATG-Client-Class-Path: lib/resources.jar lib/classes.jar

```
11:51:47,877 ERROR [nucleusNamespace] (RMI TCP Connection(3)-10.238.91.110) Unable to create class com.droplet.lookup.AllItemsDroplet for configuration /com/droplets/lookup/AllItemsDroplet java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.droplet.lookup.AllItemsDroplet from [Module "deployment.core.ear.atg_bootstrap_ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.droplet.lookup.AllItemsDroplet from [Module "deployment.core.ear.atg_bootstrap_ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at atg.nucleus.PropertyConfiguration.loadClassUsingReplacement(PropertyConfiguration.java:504) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.nucleus.PropertyConfiguration.createNewInstance(PropertyConfiguration.java:816) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.nucleus.PropertyConfiguration.createNewInstance(PropertyConfiguration.java:741) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.nucleus.NucleusNameResolver.createNewInstance(NucleusNameResolver.java:1619) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.nucleus.MultiRootNameResolver.createFromName(MultiRootNameResolver.java:833) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.nucleus.MultiRootNameResolver.resolveName(MultiRootNameResolver.java:477) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.nucleus.ResolveNameHelperImpl.resolveName(ResolveNameHelperImpl.java:274) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.nucleus.MultiRootNameResolverFactory$RequestResolveNameHelper.resolveName(MultiRootNameResolverFactory.java:832) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.DynamoHttpServletRequest.resolveNameSingleNucleus(DynamoHttpServletRequest.java:3898) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.DynamoHttpServletRequest.resolveName(DynamoHttpServletRequest.java:3857) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.DynamoHttpServletRequest.resolveName(DynamoHttpServletRequest.java:3967) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.ui.component.model.ComponentManager.setComponentActive(ComponentManager.java:658) [_DAS-UI_slib_suiclasses.jar:]
at atg.ui.component.model.ComponentAgentImpl.setComponentActive(ComponentAgentImpl.java:530) [_DAS-UI_slib_suiclasses.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at atg.security.proxy.UserSessionProxy$SessionSkeletonHandler.invoke(UserSessionProxy.java:273) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.rmi.context.ContextualSkeletonImpl.invoke(ContextualSkeletonImpl.java:127) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor115.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```

Comment: What often happens with starting out like this is that your path names are incorrect. Most often this is because your camel case in the properties file, doesn't match that of the class file. Please provide this information as well if you need more help.

Comment: @radimpe Thank you so much. I really made a dumb mistake.